# If Condition inside SqlReader.Read() While loop not executing

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sqldatareader

I am trying to validate a logged in user when they are registered by the Administrator, the users are given a `LoginID` and password of `@password` and a `LoginCount` of 0, by default. If the user eventually logs in and updates the password it gets hashed then the loginCount updates to 1. Refer to the image below:

[image]

I am trying to do multiple if statements when the user is logging in for the first time, it should check against a string password:

```
if (loginCount < 1 && password == "@password") {
```

And if the user has logged in before it should check against a hashed password using the password hashing class:

```
if(loginCount > 0 && PasswordHasher.Verify(password, hashed))
```

All this is done after the user has been filtered from the database using the LoginID:

```
select * from cor_usersetup where LoginID = @LoginID
```

but it's not working.

```
 public bool GetAuthentication(string loginId, string password) {
            var connection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FCoreDBConnection"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connection);
            string sql = "select * from cor_usersetup where LoginID = @LoginID";  // and Password = @Password 
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,cn);            
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoginID", loginId);            
            cn.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            int counter = 0;     
            while (rdr.Read()) {  
                var hashed = rdr["Password"].ToString().Trim();
                var loginCount = int.Parse(rdr["LoginCount"].ToString());                
                if (loginCount < 1 && password == "@password") {            //if the user hasnt changed his/her password yet......
                    counter = counter + 1;
                }                
                if(loginCount > 0 && PasswordHasher.Verify(password, hashed)) {     //after password confirmation..
                    counter = counter + 1;
                }
            }
            rdr.Close();
            cn.Close();
            if (counter != 0) {
                success = true;
            }            
            return success;
        }
```

I set breakpoints refer to the image below but its not hitting the `if` statements:

[image]

What am I getting wrong, and did I put my if condition properly in the right place?

Comment: You mean execution jumps from line 234 to directly line 244?

Comment: The parameter name in `Parameters.Add` should have an `@` in it according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: are you sure you are not getting and exception at line 234?

Comment: @fredrik noted thanks, i'd make that adjustments and test again.

Comment: @styx what could be the cause, because its not giving me any exception, nothing... it just executes the code and nothing works.

Comment: @AndeCaleb try to wrap the lines inside the `while` loop with `try/catch`

Comment: What value you have in LoginCount in database for the specific LoginID?

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya the LoginCount defaults to 0, after an account is being created.

Comment: So your query returns no rows, `rdr.Read()` returns false, the `while` loop is never entered, and naturally it jumps to after the loop? Have you tried pressing F10 after the breakpoint at `AddWithValue` is hit?

Comment: Have you tried running the query in management studio?

Comment: @GSerg, okay let me try that.. cos i've been trying all sorts i even restarted my system thinking it was an OS issue

Comment: Are you debugging in release configuration ? In this case Visual Studio may not hit the break points. If so, try to pass to debug mode and retest.

Comment: Debug, take the query and parameter _exactly_ the way you see it in the debugger, and try _that_ in management studio.

Comment: Every new user receives a hard-code password embedded in the application? Do you think that's secure? Is there a reason you're writing a system that's tricky to get *right* and *secure* rather than using one someone's already written?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeilever its a test system, based on clients specification how they choose their application should run. i know its not right because i thought about it too, but thats how they insisted it should be, so i am just playing by their song. hopefully if this gets sorted out, i could provided the better alternative to them.

Comment: Wrap your code to `try catch` and test it. Also, check how you build it - should be `Debug` mode not `Release`.

Answer (score -1):

Firstable, check Exceptions Window (Ctrl+Alt+E), and set all kinds of exception to throw if they doesn't. Then Debug again. 
Most possibly, your

```
    int.Parse(rdr["LoginCount"]
```

throws ArgumentException. Actually, you can use

```
    bool isConvertable = int.TryParse(rdr["LoginCount"], out int loginCount);
    if (!isConvertable)
            Console.WriteLine(rdr["LoginCount"]); //To see what you got 
    if (loginCount < 1 && password == "@password") {           
                counter = counter + 1;
            }
```

instead of int.Parse or adding try/catch block

Comment: That wouldn't cause the `if (counter != 0)` to execute.